# Global variable declaration in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand how global variables impact. Consider the below code as example

```
person = "Dave"
def display(person):
    global i 
    i = "Jack"
    print("here is ",person) 
display(person) 
display(i)
```

This results to:
here is Dave 
here is Jack

I need to understand how "here is Jack" is printed

The below code results in error that i is not defined.

```
person = "Dave"
def display(person):
    global i 
    i = "Jack"
    print("here is ",person) 
display(i)
```

I don't understand this as well.

Please favour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Gayathri**, the first thing is that **global**  keyword is used to refer the global variables declared in the program or to declare any variable as global which is going to appear inside function block (as in your case).

Let you please understand the difference between following 2 code samples.

» Using **global** keyword:

```
i = 10;

def func():
    global i;
    i = 20; # Modifying global i
    print(i); # 20

print(i); # 10
func();
print(i); # 20
```

» Without using **global** keyword:

```
i = 10;
def func():
    i = 20; # It won't modify global i, here i is local to func()
    print(i); # 20

print(i); # 10
func(); 
print(i); # 10
```

Now, let's focus on the main problem.

✓ In first case, the value of local **person** in `def display(person):` is "Dave" and it is printing `here is Dave` & after that it is creating global **i** and setting its value to 'Jack'. In second call i.e. `display(i)` is passing the set value `Jack` of **i** which is assigned to local **person** variable available in `def display(person):` and therefore it is printing `here is Jack` and no error.

[image]

✓ In second case, no explicit assignment or function call for setting value of **i** before function call `display(i)` therefore there's an error.

Comment: I wonder how value of variable ' i ' can be set as value of variable ' person '.

Comment: **@Gayathri**, please check answer again. I have updated it with a picture and let me know if you still have any issues. Thanks for commenting back. I appreciate your interest.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity , Rishikesh!

Comment: No problem **@Gayathri**. Enjoy Python. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

On the second example, when you call display, `i` is not defined yet, but in the first example, as you had called display before, `i` is defined and have a value. If you change the order in the first example, it won't work also.

`i` is only defined after a display has been called.

Comment: Thanks for your reasoning but still I wonder how value of variable ' i ' can be set as value of variable ' person '

Comment: Got it. Thanks Bruno!